# How to automatically tag chapters,sections,sub..sections and paragraphs?

Tags: luatex

I want to do a package that handles the automatic tagging of pdf documents. I try to solve the problem of taggings paragraphs with chapters, sections, subsections, subsubsections, ..., sub..sections and paragraphs with subparagraphs. I read the example of tagpdf package that performs tagging of chapters, sections, sub..sections etc., but first it only works for the names of those parts of the document and the text of the document that are not displayed in pdf, and secondly it only works for the scrbook class, but I want, if it is possible, that it works for any class of documents (I do not know if it is possible to check the class of the document via latex/lualatex). I tried to use `\everypar` commands, but as I understood, reading my log, it seems that this command is called only n+1 times, where n is the number of sections and sub...sections. My document now only needs to be compiled in lualatex. Thanks very much everybody for the help.

test_tagging_of_pars.tex

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrbook}
\usepackage{tagpdf}
\tagpdfsetup{interwordspace=true,activate-all,uncompress}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\title{test document}
\author{AlexanderKozlovskiy}
\date{\today}
%\maketitle (why this not works?)
%Marking the toc entries
%around the whole entry so only structure:
\newcommand\tagscrtocentry[1]{\tagstructbegin{tag=TOCI}#1\tagstructend}

%leaf so structure and mc:
\newcommand\tagscrtocpagenumber[1]{%
 \tagstructbegin{tag=Reference}%
 \tagmcbegin{tag=Reference}%
 #1%
 \tagmcend
 \tagstructend}

\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[
   entryformat=\tagscrtocentry,
   pagenumberformat=\tagscrtocpagenumber]{tocline}{chapter}
\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[
   entryformat=\tagscrtocentry,
   pagenumberformat=\tagscrtocpagenumber]{tocline}{section}
\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[
   entryformat=\tagscrtocentry,
   pagenumberformat=\tagscrtocpagenumber]{tocline}{subsection}
\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[
   entryformat=\tagscrtocentry,
   pagenumberformat=\tagscrtocpagenumber]{tocline}{subsubsection}
\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[
   entryformat=\tagscrtocentry,
   pagenumberformat=\tagscrtocpagenumber]{tocline}{paragraph}

\renewcommand{\addtocentrydefault}[3]{%
 \ifstr{#3}{}{}
   {%\
   \ifstr{#2}{}
    {%
     \addcontentsline{toc}{#1}
      {%
       \protect\nonumberline
       \tagstructbegin{tag=P}%
       \tagmcbegin{tag=P}%
        #3%
       \tagmcend
       \tagstructend
      }%
    }%
    {%
    \addcontentsline{toc}{#1}{%
     \tagstructbegin{tag=Lbl}%
     \tagmcbegin{tag=Lbl}%
     \protect\numberline{#2}%
     \tagmcend\tagstructend
     \tagstructbegin{tag=P}%
     \tagmcbegin{tag=P}%
      #3%
     \tagmcend
     \tagstructend
     }%
    }%
   }}%

% the dots must be marked too
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\TOCLineLeaderFill}[1][.]{%
  \leaders\hbox{$\m@th
    \mkern \@dotsep mu\hbox{\tagmcbegin{artifact}#1\tagmcend}\mkern \@dotsep
    mu$}\hfill
}

%%%%%%%%%
% Sectioning commands
%%%%%%%%

\ExplSyntaxOn
\prop_new:N   \g_tag_section_level_prop
\prop_gput:Nnn \g_tag_section_level_prop {chapter}{H1}
\prop_gput:Nnn \g_tag_section_level_prop {section}{H2}
\prop_gput:Nnn \g_tag_section_level_prop {subsection}{H3}
\prop_gput:Nnn \g_tag_section_level_prop {subsubsection}{H4}
\prop_gput:Nnn \g_tag_section_level_prop {paragraph}{H5}

%new 0.6, as attributes are local we have to put \tagmcbegin everywhere.
\renewcommand{\chapterlinesformat}[3]
 {
  \@hangfrom
   {
    \tagstructbegin{tag=\prop_item:Nn\g_tag_section_level_prop{chapter}}
    \tl_if_empty:nF{#2}
     {
      \tagmcbegin    {tag=\prop_item:Nn\g_tag_section_level_prop{chapter}}
      #2
      \tagmcend
     }
   }
   {\tagmcbegin    {tag=\prop_item:Nn\g_tag_section_level_prop{chapter}}
    #3\tagmcend\tagstructend}%
}

%unnumbered sections level give an empty mc, need to think about it.
\renewcommand{\sectionlinesformat}[4]
 {
  \@hangfrom
   {\hskip #2
    \tagstructbegin{tag=\prop_item:Nn\g_tag_section_level_prop{#1}}
    \tl_if_empty:nF{#3}
    {
     \tagmcbegin    {tag=\prop_item:Nn\g_tag_section_level_prop{#1}}
     #3
     \tagmcend
    }
   }
   {\tagmcbegin    {tag=\prop_item:Nn\g_tag_section_level_prop{#1}}
    #4
    \tagmcend\tagstructend}%
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\AfterTOCHead{\tagstructbegin{tag=TOC}}
\AfterStartingTOC{\tagstructend} %end TOC

\begin{document}
\tagstructbegin{tag=Document}
%do tagging of paragraphs
\ExplSyntaxOn
\everypar{
\message{the_size_of_stack_of_structure_elements_is_\seq_count:N \g__uftag_struct_stack_seq} %i dont know,why spaces ignore when i try input something in log,so i use _ instead of space character.
\int_case:nn {\seq_count:N \g__uftag_struct_stack_seq}
  {
   {2}{\tagstructbegin{tag=P}\tagmcbegin{tag=P}}
{4}{\tagstructend \tagstructbegin{tag=P}\tagmcbegin{tag=P}}}}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{centering}
test tagging of parts of documents\\
\end{centering}

\newpage

\tableofcontents

\newpage

\chapter{first chapter}

start testing of tagging of paragraphs

\section{test of section}

{\tiny

this is test document,which allow to do tests of tagging sections and paragraphs

\subsection{subsection 1}

test

again test

\begin{description}

\item[1] lemon

\item[2] orange

again testing of tagging parts of document

\item[3] red

\item[4] green

\end{description}}

\newpage

\subsection{new test}

end of test of tagging of document.

\ExplSyntaxOn
\int_step_inline:nnn{2}{\seq_count:N \g__uftag_struct_stack_seq }
{\tagstructend}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

There is currently no easy way to do it "for all sorts of documents" as
LaTeX and almost all classes and relevant packages are missing suitable interfaces.

Solving this is not easy. In view of the variety of implementations in this area I doubt that it will possible to solve this by some changes in the latex kernel alone.

To add the structure to a `\section` for one of the standard classes you could redefine the internal `\@sect` command of the latex kernel. But this would have no effect for classes from the KOMA-bundle or memoir or revtex4-1 and more as all either ignore or overwrite the command.

For `\part` and `\chapter` there is nothing in the kernel anyway - every class has its own implementation.

So my long term plan here is currently to develop a suitable hook system and then to convince all major classes and packages to add these hooks at the right places. Then a tagging package could simply add the tagging commands to these hooks.

I do *not* plan to extend the tagpdf package with patches for all sort of  classes and packages to get this working. The few examples are only *examples* to demonstrate that it is possible to get a structure.

Comment: So you mean,that in our days it impossible to do 100% automatic tagging of pdf document? I will look forward,what you will find way to join all classes for sectioning of document. And may be it possible to do checking,what,for example,if user of my package use memoir class we override one commands,and else another commands. Why when i use sections command \everypar called n+1 times,where n is number of sections and sub..sections,so i not see any text in my pdf document. How i can fix it and,as i wrote,how to do checking in package,what class of document user use in doc? Thanks.

Comment: Your \everypar will work only until the first sectioning command. Then it will be overwritten and is lost. You can check which class has been loaded - the kernel provides `\@ifclassloaded` for this.

Comment: Ulrike Fischer Ok,as i noticed reading my log,that perhaps after \chapter command \everypar command not call anymore,but why when i add some text with empty line (i.e paragraf )before chapter,the text of the paragraf not seeing in pdf. In my log i see,that size of structure stack is 2,but in the next paragraphs structure stack 4 instead of 3,so some struct was not closed. Help me please join your example with section with example with paragraphs,if it possible,or,if you haven't enough time,give me please idea,how i can do it myself (the document you will find in first message of this topic).

Comment: About classes: can i create list of classes and check,if class,which loaded,in this list. If true,i can override command \@sect,and if not,i can override another command (because,as i understood,for memoir and another classes,wich not supported \@sect command,we must use another command instead of \@sect),but i am not sure,that in expl3 exists function,which allow to know,if some element in list. I also want to understood,if exists command for classes with else,i.e command,which i can use instead of,for example,operator else in lua,during the checking what class was loaded.

Comment: expl3 has commands to handle lists and if-then-else switches. But there exist  many classes and creating a list of them and to check which code they would need involves a lot work.

Comment: ok and what way you propose to solve problem with diferent classes. I considered,that for some classes we can override \@sect command,and for others classes we can override another commands,i.e two checks enough,but you considered,that it require more checks? Can you please help redefine \@sect command,to save \everypar command? And i not understand that if i have size of structure stack 4 for paragraphs before section it's ok,or not? In my opinion it's not ok,because i not see the text of this paragrafs in pdf and in my opinion it must be size3 of structure stack,but i have 4.

Comment: I told you what my long term plan is and that I don't plan to patch classes or internal commands. You get 4 on the stack as you are also opening a structure through the hook in \chapterlinesformat.

Comment: Ok,i understood your idea about classes. Also i want to understand,if i must override \tableofcontents for different classes using different ways,as for chapters,sections etc,or may be it exists one way for all classes for this command? As for section exists \@sect,maybe for \tableofcontents exist more universal command to? If you will do works with section,not forget please about \everypar problem because,as i understood,there is no way now to do taggings of paragrafs,if i use chapters,sections etc. May be one way to solve it,it use again process_input_buffer calback in lua.

Answer (score 0):

Recently, this feature was added in the 2023-06-01 release of TeXLive. See https://www.latex-project.org/news/2023/06/10/issue37-of-latex2e-released/. It is relatively minimal in scope (only allows for 3 document types and does basic section/subsection/figures/some amsmath equations), but this is, as I understand it, a significant step in the right direction. The contributors also indicate that they are working to expand the scope of automatic tagging in subsequent releases.